# Uploading custom metadata with Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, metadata, firebase-storage

I have an app where I want to store a caption with a photo, but in my case, I'm using FIRStorage to store the photos. Everything's working there, but I want to store the caption in the photo metadata. Don't ask why, it just makes sense for my project specifically.

```
let meta = FIRStorageMetadata.init(dictionary: ["customMetadata" :
["caption" : self.textField.text!]])
                let imageRef = storageRef.child(iid)
            imageRef.put(uploadData, metadata: meta, completion: {     (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        //failure
                        print(error)
                        return
                    } else {

                    //success
                    print(metadata)

                }
            })
```

As you can see, I'm even setting up the metadata constant exactly how Firebase tells us in their documentation. When I pass meta into metadata in the `.put`, why does it not use my custom metadata? Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! I just did it wrong previously.
Here is the solution:

```
var meta = FIRStorageMetadata()
meta.customMetadata = ["caption" : self.textField.text!]
```

Then you pass meta into metadata parameter in `.put`